# Why is it that I can run R from Terminal but not Julia?

Tags: installation

When I type r in my Mac OSX terminal, it sends me straight into the R application, but if I type julia, it tells me "path not found" although I installed Julia as well.

Why could this be?

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the `julia` binary was not found within one of the directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable. Since Julia is distributed as a MacOS X application, it doesn't start up from the command line without a helper command.

Try this script in `/usr/local/bin` - call it `julia`:

```
#!/bin/ksh
VERSION=${1:0.3.2}
exec '/Applications/Julia-$VERSION.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia'
```

The last line is what the MacOS X Julia actually runs.

You could also try this script, but it is a bit riskier - if you have duplicate Julia install, it could get confused:

```
#!/bin/ksh
exec $(ls -1d /Applications/Julia-*.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia)
```

The reason that R runs directly but Julia does not is possibly that the R application is an actual X11 application, where as the distributed Julia application is a MacOS-style application, even if it runs in the Terminal.

Hope this helps!